# c# renci ssh command output differs from client to client

Tags: c#, ssh.net

Something really odd is happening to me.

I have ssh command which executes python script on my remote server.
When I execute it through PuTTY it works like it should and desired output is shown. But when executed through my C# app using ssh.net it always returns some old data that's long time gone from the server (which is freebsd 9.3).

Here's how I execute my command and catch output:

```
var task = new Task(() => {
    var ret = ssh_instance.CreateCommand("cd /home/" + "python python_script.py -param");
    ret.Execute();
    FlexibleMessageBox.Show(ret.Result);
});
task.Start();
```

It seems literally unexplainable to me so I would be really thankful if someone could enlighten me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post as an answer at the moment, but I don't see any specification to connect to a remote server in that command, which makes me believe it's running a copy of that script that happens to reside locally on your machine at that path? Was there code left out of this for brevity that would show the remote connection?

Comment: I can only give you general Information. SSH and all other encryption works on a shared secret. The two encryption options are symetric and asymetric. Asymetric is very secure, but also ways too slow for bulk data. So we do not use it for that. What we use it for instead is key exchange: After the SSH tunnel is made, a random "Session key" is generated by one side. That is the exchanged via the SSH tunnel. All the actually data is encrypted symetrically using that random key. I guess you are asuming the key generation and exchange happened Automagically, when it is something you have to do.

Comment: The creation of `ssh_instance` handles all issues with connecting to the server and key handling. Neither comment is helpful.

Comment: In C#, `&&` can't be applied to two strings. Either you code as shown is not what you are running, or you have missed a compiler error.

Comment: What commands are you trying to run on the remote host?  The + in your command string will just concatenate to "cd /home/python python_script.py -param"   I don't think that is what you are trying to run.

Answer (score -1):

Please remember.

1. Connection will closed after calling "CreateCommand()" method.
2. You need to read all of received data from your stream against your each command.

   --> In my opinion, this is a reason why you've got old result from your connection.

So, I try to use Renci.SshNet.ShellStream class. in my code was,

```
    private Renci.SshNet.SshClient _client = null;
    private Renci.SshNet.ShellStream shellStream = null;

    private void connect()
    {
        try
        {
            this.disConnect();
            _client = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(cboUri.Text, tbxSrvUsr.Text, tbxSrvPW.Text);
            //_client.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<Renci.SshNet.Common.ExceptionEventArgs>(_client_ErrorOccurred);
            //_client.HostKeyReceived += new EventHandler<Renci.SshNet.Common.HostKeyEventArgs>(_client_HostKeyReceived);

            _client.Connect();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            shellStream = _client.CreateShellStream("Jornathan", 80, 24, 800, 800, 1024);
            shellStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null, null);


            shellStream.DataReceived += new EventHandler<Renci.SshNet.Common.ShellDataEventArgs>(shellStream_DataReceived);

            tbxStatus.Text = "Connected";            

            this.btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            this.cboServerList.Enabled = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and add method to read all text from server.
Please remember, you should read all text until encounter received data size is "0". refer as below.

```
    private void readOutput()
    {
        do
        {
            string strOutput = shellStream.ReadLine();
            if (strOutput != null && strOutput.Length > 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
                this.SetStatusText(strOutput);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        } while (true);
    }
```

And then add event handler, that's it!.

```
    private System.Threading.Thread Thread_OutputHandle = null;

    private void shellStream_DataReceived(object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.ShellDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Thread_OutputHandle == null)
        {

            Thread_OutputHandle = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(readOutput));
            Thread_OutputHandle.Start();
        }
        else if (Thread_OutputHandle.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            Thread_OutputHandle.Abort();

            Thread_OutputHandle = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(readOutput));
            Thread_OutputHandle.Start();
        }            
    }
```

Others:
I hope to remember where I've got help to make this code.
but I can't.

Please let me know when you find location of code that I've got help.
I'll add its location to here.

Comment: *"In my opinion, this is a reason why you've got old result from your connection."* - I cannot imagine, how do the previous sentences explain the OP's problem.

Comment: Sorry too late response, I agree with you. it couldn't explain original question.
It is not the same situation as the question, but it is based on experience and is not direct cause and effect.